# Python BeautifulSoup can't select specific tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My problem is when parsing a website and then loading the data tree with BS. How can I look for the content of an `<em>` Tag? I tried

```
for first in soup.find_all("li", class_="li-in"):
    print first.select("em.fl.in-date").string

                   #or

    print first.select("em.fl.in-date").contents
```

but it doesnt work. Pls help.

I am searching for cars on tutti.ch

Here is my entire code:

```
#Crawl tutti.ch
import urllib
thisurl = "http://www.tutti.ch/stgallen/fahrzeuge/autos"
handle = urllib.urlopen(thisurl)
html_gunk =  handle.read()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_gunk, 'html.parser')

for first in soup.find_all("li", class_="li-in"):
    if first.a.string and "Audi" and "BMW" in first.a.string:
        print "Geschafft: %s" % first.a.contents
        print first.select("em.fl.in-date").string
    else:
        print first.a.contents
```

When it finds a bmw or audi it should check for when the car was inserted. The time is located in an em-Tag like this:

`<em class="fl in-date">
Heute
<br></br>
13:59
</em>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 first.select("em.fl.in-date").text
```

Assuming your selector is correct.  You didn't provide which URL you're scraping, so I can't be sure.

```
>>> url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187213/python-beautifulsoup"
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.find_all("p")[0].text
u'My problem is when parsing a website and then loading the data tree with BS. How can I look for the content of an <em> Tag? I tried '
```

After seeing your code, I made the following change, take a look:

```
#Crawl tutti.ch
import urllib
thisurl = "http://www.tutti.ch/stgallen/fahrzeuge/autos"
handle = urllib.urlopen(thisurl)
html_gunk =  handle.read()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_gunk, 'html.parser')

for first in soup.find_all("li", class_="li-in"):
    if first.a.string and "Audi" and "BMW" in first.a.string:
        print "Geschafft: %s" % first.a.contents
        print first.select("em.fl.in-date")[0].text
    else:
        print first.a.contents
```

Comment: Thank you so much Adam Barnes. Your code works perfectly!!

Comment: `and "Audi"` is always going to be True